# Preprocessor variable when using Adobe Alchemy

Tags: c++, flash, gcc, llvm, alchemy

I'm porting a cross-platform lib I use to Alchemy. One particular file has a block of code similar to this :

```
#if defined(WIN32)
    // Do some Windows-specific stuff
#elif defined(__linux__)
    // Do some linux-specific stuff
#endif
```

I now need to add Flash-specific code (NOP in some cases), but so far I've been unable to find what does Alchemy's GCC define to identify itself! I tried `FLASH` and a couple others but nothing seems to work.

BTW, is it me or Alchemy's documentation is almost non-existent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I ended up adding `-DFLASH` to my makefiles.